# Cant mock objects on my android project

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, mockito

I cant Mock any object on my test cases. So i must be doing something wrong. I can run my test cases without, and that works fine. But as soon as i try to mock an object. I get the following error when i try to run the test case.

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass
(ClassImposterizer.java:85)
```

I run my android project on *Android Studio*. and here is how my gradle file looks like

> ```
> apply plugin: 'android'
> ```
>
> dependencies {
>       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
>       compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
>       compile project(':facebook-sdk_lib')
>       compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
>       compile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5" }
>
> android {
>
> ```
> packagingOptions {
>     exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
>     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
>     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
> }
>
> compileSdkVersion 19
> buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
>
> lintOptions {
>     abortOnError false
> }
>
> sourceSets {
>     main {
>         manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
>         java {
>             srcDir 'src'
>             srcDir 'src-gen'
>             srcDir 'tests'
>         }
>         resources {
>             srcDir 'src'
>             srcDir 'src-gen'
>         }
>         aidl.srcDirs = ['src','src-gen']
>         renderscript.srcDirs = ['src','src-gen']
>         res.srcDirs = ['res']
>         assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
>     }
>     androidTest.setRoot('tests')
>
>     debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
>     release.setRoot('build-types/release')
> } }
> ```

I do not know if there is a big problem with it. 
Also here is one of my test classes

```
    public class ValueFormatTest extends AndroidTestCase
{

  public ValueFormatTest()
  {
    /* Do Nothing! */
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see junit.framework.TestCase#setUp()
   */
  protected void setUp() throws Exception
  {
    super.setUp();
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see junit.framework.TestCase#tearDown()
   */
  protected void tearDown() throws Exception
  {
    super.tearDown();
  }

  public final void testFormaterDateTime()
  {
    Mockito.mock(BaseConnection.class);

    Assert.assertEquals("",ValueFormat.formatDateTime(getContext(),2,null));
    Assert.assertEquals("",ValueFormat.formatDateTime(getContext(),1,null));
    Assert.assertEquals("",ValueFormat.formatDateTime(getContext(), -1, null));
  }
}
```

And lastly this could help understand how my class hierarchy looks like. If that even helps

```
ProjectFolder
-.idea
-build
-DaoGenerator
-Facebook
-google-play-services
-ModuleCar
   |-libs
   |-build
   |-src
   |-src-gen
   |-tests
      |-lib
      |-res
      |-src.com.car.test
```

Any help that will get me to the right path of fixing this issue is welcome. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. In the `gradle.build` file. I changed how i imported Mockito. 
The problem was that it could not find the dexmaker.

```
    compile("org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5") 
    {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    }
    compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.1'
    compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.1'
```